# grab div element and all it's contents by class and append to another div

Tags: jquery

i have a table and i'm trying to take the div's in the table (by class: product_li) and i'm trying to place them into another div element named "upsell". How do i do this? here's what my table looks like:

```
<table cellspacing="0" class="productTable"><tr><td id="catProdTd_6732684" class="productItem"><div class="product_li item-on-sale-0 aaronBell hide">
    <div class="grid_3">
        <img class="sale-0" src="/images/sale.png" />
        <div class="prev">
            <a href="/store/prints/gold-snake-and-skull"><img id="catsproduct_6732684" src="/images/Artists/Aaron-Bell/777.jpg" alt="Gold Snake and Skull" border="0" /></a>
        </div><!-- .prev -->
    </div><!-- .grid_3 -->

    <div class="grid_4">
        <div class="entry_content">
            <a href="/store/prints/gold-snake-and-skull"><h3 class="title">Gold Snake and Skull</h3></a>

            <p>Dimensions 12x15"<br />High Dynamic Range (HDR) Pigments<br />Printed on 100% Cotton Rag</p>

<span class="favorite-link">#6732684#<a class="favoritelink" href="/FavoriteProcess.aspx?OID=6732684&amp;OTYPE=27">[+] favorites</a></span> | <a class="more" href="/store/prints/gold-snake-and-skull">Learn More</a>

        </div><!-- .entry_content -->
    </div><!-- .grid_4 -->

    <div class="grid_2">
        <div class="cart">
            <div class="price">
                <div class="price_new">$39.95</div>
                <div class="price_old">$59.95</div>
            </div>
            <span class="btn-buy"><input class="productSubmitInput" name="AddToCart_Submit" type="submit" value="Buy Now" onclick="AddToCart(208719,6732684,'',3,'','',true);return false;" /></span>
        </div><!-- .cart -->
    </div><!-- .grid_2 -->

    <div class="clear"></div>
</div></td><td id="catProdTd_6732685" class="productItem"><div class="product_li item-on-sale-0 aaronBell hide">
    <div class="grid_3">
        <img class="sale-0" src="/images/sale.png" />
        <div class="prev">
            <a href="/store/prints/namakubi"><img id="catsproduct_6732685" src="/images/Artists/Aaron-Bell/500.jpg" alt="Namakubi" border="0" /></a>
        </div><!-- .prev -->
    </div><!-- .grid_3 -->

    <div class="grid_4">
        <div class="entry_content">
            <a href="/store/prints/namakubi"><h3 class="title">Namakubi</h3></a>

            <p>Dimensions 12x15"<br />High Dynamic Range (HDR) Pigments<br />Printed on 100% Cotton Rag</p>

<span class="favorite-link">#6732685#<a class="favoritelink" href="/FavoriteProcess.aspx?OID=6732685&amp;OTYPE=27">[+] favorites</a></span> | <a class="more" href="/store/prints/namakubi">Learn More</a>

        </div><!-- .entry_content -->
    </div><!-- .grid_4 -->

    <div class="grid_2">
        <div class="cart">
            <div class="price">
                <div class="price_new">$39.95</div>
                <div class="price_old">$59.95</div>
            </div>
            <span class="btn-buy"><input class="productSubmitInput" name="AddToCart_Submit" type="submit" value="Buy Now" onclick="AddToCart(208719,6732685,'',3,'','',true);return false;" /></span>
        </div><!-- .cart -->
    </div><!-- .grid_2 -->

    <div class="clear"></div>
</div></td><td id="catProdTd_6732686" class="productItem"><div class="product_li item-on-sale-0 adamHays hide">
    <div class="grid_3">
        <img class="sale-0" src="/images/sale.png" />
        <div class="prev">
            <a href="/store/prints/no-time-to-lose"><img id="catsproduct_6732686" src="/images/Artists/Adam Hays/1128.jpg" alt="No Time To Lose" border="0" /></a>
        </div><!-- .prev -->
    </div><!-- .grid_3 -->

    <div class="grid_4">
        <div class="entry_content">
            <a href="/store/prints/no-time-to-lose"><h3 class="title">No Time To Lose</h3></a>

            <p>Dimensions 12x16"<br />High Dynamic Range (HDR) Pigments<br />Printed on 100% Cotton Rag</p>

<span class="favorite-link">#6732686#<a class="favoritelink" href="/FavoriteProcess.aspx?OID=6732686&amp;OTYPE=27">[+] favorites</a></span> | <a class="more" href="/store/prints/no-time-to-lose">Learn More</a>

        </div><!-- .entry_content -->
    </div><!-- .grid_4 -->

    <div class="grid_2">
        <div class="cart">
            <div class="price">
                <div class="price_new">$39.95</div>
                <div class="price_old">$59.95</div>
            </div>
            <span class="btn-buy"><input class="productSubmitInput" name="AddToCart_Submit" type="submit" value="Buy Now" onclick="AddToCart(208719,6732686,'',3,'','',true);return false;" /></span>
        </div><!-- .cart -->
    </div><!-- .grid_2 -->

    <div class="clear"></div>
</div></td><td id="catProdTd_6732687" class="productItem"><div class="product_li item-on-sale-1 adamHays hide">
    <div class="grid_3">
        <img class="sale-1" src="/images/sale.png" />
        <div class="prev">
            <a href="/store/prints/reaper"><img id="catsproduct_6732687" src="/images/Artists/Adam Hays/1140.jpg" alt="Reaper" border="0" /></a>
        </div><!-- .prev -->
    </div><!-- .grid_3 -->

    <div class="grid_4">
        <div class="entry_content">
            <a href="/store/prints/reaper"><h3 class="title">Reaper</h3></a>

            <p>Dimensions 24x16"<br />High Dynamic Range (HDR) Pigments<br />Printed on 100% Cotton Rag</p>

<span class="favorite-link">#6732687#<a class="favoritelink" href="/FavoriteProcess.aspx?OID=6732687&amp;OTYPE=27">[+] favorites</a></span> | <a class="more" href="/store/prints/reaper">Learn More</a>

        </div><!-- .entry_content -->
    </div><!-- .grid_4 -->

    <div class="grid_2">
        <div class="cart">
            <div class="price">
                <div class="price_new">$39.95</div>
                <div class="price_old"><span style="text-decoration:line-through;">$69.95</span></div>
            </div>
            <span class="btn-buy"><input class="productSubmitInput" name="AddToCart_Submit" type="submit" value="Buy Now" onclick="AddToCart(208719,6732687,'',3,'','',true);return false;" /></span>
        </div><!-- .cart -->
    </div><!-- .grid_2 -->

    <div class="clear"></div>
</div></td></tr></table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this.

```
$(".product_li").each(function()
{
  $("#upsell").append($(this).html());
});
```

If you want to remove the divs from the table after there appended to upsell, you can do $(this).remove(); in the loop.

To get the element itself you could clone it.

```
$(".product_li").each(function()
{
  $("#upsell").append($(this).clone());
});
```

Comment: I need it to grab also the product_li div.This doesn't seem to grab the .product_li div.I tried doing, instead of .product_li, .productItem but that doesn't seem to work because the main image is also in a .productItem. How do i include .product_li itself into the append portion?

Comment: Try $("#upsell").append($(this).clone()); in the loop. that should clone it and everything within it.

Comment: awesome! you learn something new everyday!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to add the container div then you can use something like:

```
$('body').append('<div id="#upsell"></div>');
```

*note: Replace `body` with whatever container div you need the products to go into.*

Then this will iterate through each instance of .product_li and append it to a div with the id #upsell:

```
$('.product_li').each(function() {
    $('#upsell').append($(this).html());
});
```

Then you could run the following to remove the table:

```
$('.productTable').remove();
```

Comment: I need it to grab also the product_li div.This doesn't seem to grab the .product_li div.I tried doing, instead of .product_li, .productItem but that doesn't seem to work because the main image is also in a .productItem. How do i include .product_li itself into the append portion?

Comment: Hi Damien, that's exactly what this is doing. It's grabbing each .product_li div (and its contents) and inserting it into a new div.